# Copying different selected excel range into different word files

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to vba and I have searched now for ages on the internet a solution to my issue.
The project is that I have on an excel worksheet a list of recipes with different steps that looks like this:

```
RecipeName    RecipeDescription   Time    Step   StepDescription   Results
Burger        Bread + Meat        Short   Step1  Open Bread        Bread open    
Burger        Bread + Meat        Short   Step2  Cook Meat         Meat cooked    
Soup          Veggie              Short   Step1  Instant soup      Soup done
```

I am easily able to define a range and paste it into one word  document but the tricky part is here:  
 
I would like to have 1 word document per recipe, containing first the recipe name, description and time header with the actual recipe name, description and time just below. Then it will be followed by each step number, description and results.
So it would look like this:

```
Burger
------
RecipeName    RecipeDescription   Time
Burger        Bread + Meat        Short

Step1         Open Bread          Bread open
Step2         Cook Meat           Meat cooked

Soup
----
RecipeName    RecipeDescription   Time
Soup          Veggie              Short

Step1         Instant soup        Soup done
```

As stated before I can copy the header and paste it in one word but the difficulty is to select the steps of each recipes and put it into word then saving the word file into a predefined directory (the save part is already done and working).

The idea I had was to take the recipe name as a way to sort if we are still in the same recipe or if we jumped to another.

Functionally, it would be like this:

```
For i = 2 to lastRow
  Open and activate a new word file
  For j = 2 to lastRow      
   If Cells(j,1) = Cells(j+1; 1) Then
   Copy Step, Step Description and Results of row(j)
   Paste into word file
  Next j
   Else
   Copy Step, Step Description and Results of row(i)
   Paste into word file
   Save the word file
   i = j 'So i takes the value of j
Next i
```

But I have issues between i and j...

For the moment my code looks like this but please excuse me for the amateur look of it:

```
    Sub ExceltoWord()

    ' 'This part of the code will paste the information into word

    Dim descriptionHeader As Range
    Dim stepHeader As Range
    Dim step As Range
    Dim descriptionTest As Range
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WordTable As Word.Table

    ' this part of the code will call the rootfolder creation part

    'Call NewFolder

    ' Will Set the title and descrption header
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ToWord").Activate
    Set descriptionHeader = Range("A1:C1")
    Set stepHeader = Range("D1:F1")

    'Have the last row stored for later
    lastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Create an Instance of MS Word
    On Error Resume Next

    'Is MS Word already opened?
    Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
    Err.Clear

    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
    If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")

    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
    If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    'Make MS Word Visible and Active
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.Activate

    'Copy Excel Table Range Paste Table into MS Word
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
        descriptionHeader.Paste
        'Need a part here to paste the actual recipe name, description and time

        For j = 2 To lastRow
        If Cells(i, 1).Content = Cells(i + 1, 1).Content Then
            Cells(i, 6).Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Range("A1:C1").Select
            With WordApp.Selection
            .TypeText Text:=Cell.Text
            .TypeParagraph
            End With
        Next j
        Else 
            Cells(i, 6).Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Range("A1:C1").Select
            With WordApp.Selection
            .TypeText Text:=Cell.Text
            .TypeParagraph
            End With

    Next i

EndRoutine:
'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

It has been weeks now that I am stuck on the Excel to word part as I have gigantic difficulties sorting out how to loop into the recipes and have one word file saved for each of them.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't test it right now, but your loop should look somewhat like that:

```
Dim RecipeName As String
Dim DocPath As String
Dim RecipeText As String
DocPath = "C:\.....\"

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ToWord")
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If .Cells(i, 1).Value <> RecipeName Then    'New Recipe
            If Not myDoc Is Nothing Then
                myDoc.Range().Text = RecipeText
                myDoc.SaveAs DocPath & RecipeName & ".doc"
                myDoc.Close False
            End If
            RecipeName = .Cells(i, 1).Value
            Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
            RecipeText = .Cells(i, 1) & vbCrLf & "-----" & vbCrLf & .Cells(1, 1) & vbTab & .Cells(1, 2) & vbTab & .Cells(1, 3) & vbCrLf
            RecipeText = RecipeText & .Cells(i, 1) & vbTab & .Cells(i, 2) & vbTab & .Cells(i, 3) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
        End If

        RecipeText = RecipeText & .Cells(i, 4) & vbTab & .Cells(i, 5) & vbTab & .Cells(i, 6) & vbCrLf
    Next i
    myDoc.Range().Text = RecipeText
    myDoc.SaveAs DocPath & RecipeName & ".doc"
    myDoc.Close False
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer I will try it and give an update on the results

Comment: Jochen, thank your very much. It works like a charm. I had to modify the tabulation and vbCrLf to give a better layout to the word document but other than that it is perfect. When I tried to state my condition as .Cells(i,1) = .Cells(i+1,1), the simple solution was to have a condition as different and store the value to be compared with. Very simple, but in my opinion pure genius.